# Ignore margin for pseudo-elements :before or :after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mark borders for the given set of general HTML elements (their CSS is not under my control) in a way that the borders are visible, and they are highlighted on hover.

I am currently using pseudo-elements :before and :after to achieve this, but I am struggling with the margins. I need to use CSS for that, not JS.

The desired behavior is to only have a single line between any two elements, but because of the margins, the borders are duplicated between paragraph "Some content" and heading "World".

I am able to apply marker classes either to wrapping divs or directly to class elements as shown in the below snippet, both is OK for me.

```css
.mark-borders:before,
.mark-borders:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #ccc;
}

.mark-borders:hover:before,
.mark-borders:hover:after
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mark-borders">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="mark-borders">
  <p>
   Some content
  </p>
</div>
<div class="mark-borders">
  <h1>
    World
  </h1>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<div class="mark-borders">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>
<p class="mark-borders">
 Some content
</p>
<h1 class="mark-borders">
  World
</h1>
```

Is there some way how to "merge" the borders between to a single one while preserving the hover highlight effect without using JS to place the border lines?

I have tried using :after for all, and :before only for the very first element, but in that case I am either loosing the hover effect for the top border, or it displays in wrong location (same problem as with original borders).

---

**UPDATE:**

I was able to put together almost working solution with the following concept:

- Each element displays its :before border
- The last element displays also its :after border
- hover activates :before border of current element and :before border of its next sibling

But ... even that it works better than original, the "margin" area is dead, not responding to :hover, any ideas how it could be fixed?

Updated code:

```css
.mark-borders:before,
.mark-borders:last-child:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #ccc;
}

.mark-borders:hover:before,
.mark-borders:hover:last-child:after,
.mark-borders:hover + *:before
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <h1>
      Hello
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <h1>
      World
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You wanted to use 1 border for each div. right?

Comment: Yes, I want to have one displayed border between each of the divs, plus border before first and after last, BUT i need both before and after border to highlight on hover. I was just able to come up with a half-way solution, I will update the question with my progress in a moment.

Comment: ahh. I got it. just Put this `.mark-borders{overflow:hidden}` and reposition your before and after accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive edited your code and came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/7g31c5rp/4/

```
.mark-borders:nth-of-type(2):after,
  p.mark-borders:after{
  display: none;
}
.mark-borders:hover + .mark-borders:before{
   border-bottom: solid 1px red;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

removing the some-content after and targeting the WORLD before on hover.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with similar concept in the meantime. I also cannot selectively add classes to only some elements, I need to apply the same class to all children of a single parent node.

Comment: I can't rely on specific element types either, it needs to work on a general flat list of elements with a specific extra class (mark-borders in my case). Your solution has also the same behavior as the one I already have. Any idea how to make the margin areas responding to :hover in either mine or your solution?

Comment: I think you should use javascript

Comment: ahh. I got it. just Put this .mark-borders{overflow:hidden} and reposition your before and after accordingly.

Comment: I see, so it seems to me that overflow:hidden turns margin behavior to more like padding behavior, but in that case I have margins applied from both sides (the content expands more than it should). But interesting to know that something like this is possible, thanks for that! By reposition before and after you mean by javascript, right?

Answer (score 1):

Only add a border `:before`, using sibling selectors.
Then give an `:after` border to the `:last-child`

```css
.mark-borders:before,
.mark-borders + .mark-borders:before,
.mark-borders:last-child:after
{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #ccc;
}

.mark-borders:hover:before,
.mark-borders:hover + .mark-borders:before,
.mark-borders:last-child:hover:after
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <h1>
      Hello
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mark-borders">
    <h1>
      World
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems promising at the first sight, but I am not allowed to influence the positioning of the original elements, just have to mark borders, that is why I used position: absolute in my example. Your solution adds additional (unwanted) space. Any idea how to do that without changing the original underlying design?

Comment: @martinh_kentico Have a look at my updated snippet. I guess that should be it?

Comment: This is exactly what I already have in my updated question, but the margin areas are not responding to :hover, any ideas how that could be fixed?

Comment: I am starting to think it may not be possible without relaxing some constraints first. Could you provide more info as to why you are only able to add _one_ class, etc.